# constructing transactions for Fantom

Tags: transactions, gas, gas-price, signature, fantom

Below is my attempt at constructing a transaction on Fantom

(Keep in mind that Fantom is not EIP-1559 compatible, so the format should be the old one)

```
contract_txn = contract_SPOOKY_ROUTER.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(Web3.toWei(1.2, 'ether'), 0, path , address_wallet, block['timestamp']+60 ).buildTransaction({
                                'type': '0x2',
                                'chainId':  250,    # FTM 
                               # 'value' : Web3.toWei(1.5, 'ether'),
                                'gas': 200000,
                                'gasPrice': Web3.toWei('200', 'gwei'),
                                'nonce': nonce,
    })
signed = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(contract_txn, privatekey)
w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction)
nonce += 1
```

When I run this, I end up with the following error message.

```
    raise TypeError("Unknown kwargs: {0}".format(sorted(unknown_kwargs)))
TypeError: Unknown kwargs: ['gasPrice']
```

I am having a hard time figuring out where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Type 2 is for EIP-1559 London fork.
Use maxFeePerGas and maxPriorityFeePerGas, when using type 2.
If the chain doesn't support it, remove type parameter.